# Can you crack the code?

Tags: cipher, encoded-message

```
I GMMA OBBK GKONYQ TC WWA ZTS KCSD SM PKGPX.
GEST MBG ROC BOK KMUUU FDU IAONXJJ, JWS EQDD RA LGXC.
EWU IS GP JJN TK VQHM NE TD BMLSX.
KRQE LTAH!
```

Hint (if you want one):

> The letter substitutions are not "one-to-one", eg. a letter isn't usually encoded into the same letter multiple times.

Comment: These puzzles are in a category called [mass-producible puzzles](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/179/are-specific-coded-message-puzzles-on-topic-in-puzzling/180#180), which are generally off-topic.

Comment: @Joe, hard to say that without knowing the cipher. E.g. if it's something original then that wouldn't be an m p p (IMO).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cipher is a simple incremental cipher. Each character in the code is $L-n$ where $L$ is the numerical position of the letter in the alphabet and $n$ is the index of the character in the encrypted text.

I actually solved it by guessing the last line first, and then reverse-engineering that makes it quite obvious what the cipher is.

Working through the message, it decrypts as

> I HOPE THIS PUZZLE IS NOT TOO HARD TO SOLVE
>  ONCE YOU GET THE FIRST FEW LETTERS, THE REST IS EASY
>  BUT IT IS NOT AS HARD AS IT SEEMS
>  GOOD LUCK!

It would be nice if you don't make it so so so long next time though ^_^

Comment: You got it! I didn't think that making it long would be a problem because I did the encoding using Python. Sorry! :)